# Failed posting to CloudWatch: Error running child : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr, amazon-cloudwatch

I am attempting to post to Cloudwatch from my EMR job, but I keep getting the error from stderr:

> Error: com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance()Lcom/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
>   Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
>   Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
>   Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

and from syslog:

> 2017-06-20 16:58:23,078 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance()Lcom/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
>       at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.resolveCredentials(AwsClientBuilder.java:125)
>       at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.access$100(AwsClientBuilder.java:52)
>       at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder$SyncBuilderParams.(AwsClientBuilder.java:412)
>       at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.getSyncClientParams(AwsClientBuilder.java:354)
>       at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
>       at MapJoltSpec.cleanup(MapJoltSpec.java:186)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:149)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:796)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

I have attached the role CloudWatchFullAccess on the EC2 instances and added to the pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.151</version>
    </dependency>
```

Finally here is my code attempting to post in the cleanup method of my mapreduce job:

```
    final AmazonCloudWatch cw =
            AmazonCloudWatchClientBuilder.defaultClient();

    Dimension dimension = new Dimension()
            .withName("POST_COUNT")
            .withValue("SUCCESFUL_POST_COUNT");

    MetricDatum datum = new MetricDatum()
            .withMetricName("SUCCESFUL_POST_COUNT")
            .withUnit(StandardUnit.None)
            .withValue(2.0)
            .withDimensions(dimension);

    PutMetricDataRequest request = new PutMetricDataRequest()
            .withNamespace("test-ElasticMapReduce")
            .withMetricData(datum);

    PutMetricDataResult response = cw.putMetricData(request);
    System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: It seems your package missing those required jars. Did you check job jar has AWS jars?

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: You need to check the package.

Comment: How would I check the package? I seems to have libraries on my local.

Comment: `0 Mon Jun 19 19:51:20 EDT 2017 com/amazonaws/auth/ 0 Mon Jun 19 19:51:20 EDT 2017 com/amazonaws/auth/presign/
0 Mon Jun 19 19:51:18 EDT 2017 com/amazonaws/auth/policy/
0 Mon Jun 19 19:51:20 EDT 2017 com/amazonaws/auth/policy/conditions/
0 Mon Jun 19 19:51:20 EDT 2017 com/amazonaws/auth/policy/internal/
0 Mon Jun 19 19:51:20 EDT 2017 com/amazonaws/auth/internal/
0 Mon Jun 19 19:51:20 EDT 2017 com/amazonaws/auth/profile/
0 Mon Jun 19 19:51:20 EDT 2017 com/amazonaws/auth/profile/internal/
0 Mon Jun 19 19:51:20 EDT 2017 com/amazonaws/auth/profile/internal/securitytoken/`

Comment: if you mean by running If you mean by running` jar tvf 'myJar'`, then the output is as above